# Navbar not updating state while user logged in unless refresh page in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**Navbar.jsx**

```
const [user, setUser] = useState("")

const fetchUser = async() => {
    const userData = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
    if(userData){
        setUser(userData.username)
    } 
}


useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser()
}, [user])
```

**Login.jsx**

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext)
const navigate = useNavigate()

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try{
        const user = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/user/login",{
            email, password
        })
        // setUser(data)
        console.log(user.data)
        if(user.data.token){
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user.data.data))
        }

        console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"))
        alert("Login Success")
        navigate('/')
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
        alert("Failed to Login")
    }
    console.log(user)
}
```

I am trying to login the user and have the navbar state updating while the user clicked the login button but even the page stored the data on local storage and I used `useEffect` to fetch the user state, the navbar still not updating the login state unless I refresh the page. Are there any solutions to have the navbar updating upon clicking the login button instead of till refreshing the page the state changing?

Comment: Do not store all user information in the localstorage , only store the token generated from the backend in the local storage.
Secondly, for showing the username in the header you can use the context api approach.
As you login to the application api will automatically be called and username and all othe data will be available to all other components

Comment: How to use context to store the local storage?

Comment: You will not get the data from the local storage, will just hit a api which will get the data from the backend database